# how to check username exit or not two different table in djnago rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

*while register new user in Tempdriver table need to varify username already exist or not in tempdriver table and appuser table, if check tempdriver table username its working but if i check appuser table getting error, pls someone help me out.*

**models.py-** *add models Tempdriver and Appuser*

```
class Tempdriver(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True,null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True,null=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class AppUser(BaseModel):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**seriliazers.py**

```
class TempDriverUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Tempdriver
        fields=('username','mobile')
    def validate(self,username):       
        user=Tempdriver.objects.filter(username=username)
        user_exists = AppUser.objects.filter(username=username)
        if  user.exists() and user_exists.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("UserName already exists")
        
    def validate_mobile(self, mobile):
        mobile=Tempdriver.objects.filter(mobile=mobile)
        if mobile.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Mobile Number already exists")
```

**views.py**

```
class Tempuserapi(APIView):
 
    parser_classes=(MultiPartParser,FormParser)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = TempDriverUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status= HTTP_200_OK)
```

**trace report**

```
ERROR Internal Server Error: /api/tempusercheck/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner   
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception 
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\api\views.py", line 632, in post
    if serializer.is_valid():
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 220, in is_valid   
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "E:\10dec_everestfleet\everest_jarvis\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 423, in run_validation
    assert value is not None, '.validate() should return the validated data'
AssertionError: .validate() should return the validated data
ERROR "POST /api/tempusercheck/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20285
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def validate_username(self,value):
        data = self.get_initial()
        username = data.get('username')
        tempdriver = Tempdriver.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
        appuser = AppUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
        if tempdriver :
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Username already exists")
        if appuser:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Username already exists")
        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the validated data as the error said.

```
class TempDriverUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Tempdriver
        fields=('username','mobile')

    def validate_username(self,username):       
        user=Tempdriver.objects.filter(username=username)
        user_exists = AppUser.objects.filter(username=username)
        if  user.exists() and user_exists.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("UserName already exists")
        return username

    def validate_mobile(self, mobile):
        mobile=Tempdriver.objects.filter(mobile=mobile)
        if mobile.exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Mobile Number already exists")
        return mobile
```

Comment: while applied this code it will create new username  in tempdriver table , i need to varify username exit or not both table that's it, kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning anything in validate. change your validate to

```
def validate(self,attrs):
    username = attrs.get('username')
    user=Tempdriver.objects.filter(username=username)
    user_exists = AppUser.objects.filter(username=username)
    if  user.exists() and user_exists.exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("UserName already exists")
    return attrs
```

also return mobile in your validate_mobile too

Comment: its return username but i want to return return "username already exists"

Comment: we don't return username. serializers.ValidationError("UserName already exists") will return "username already exists" if all validations pass then we return data

Comment: i mean to say i post appuser table username it will create new user in tempdriver table while applied this code, at same time if any user already exist in tempdriver then validation errror showing(username already exit ), in appuser table validation not getting applied

Comment: @ Abdul Raffay only tempdriver table validation check, appuser table validation not getting check